# How to clean all data from a specific remote in git?

Tags: git

I have a git repo for which I use two different remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  http://user@10.0.1.1/git/repo.git (fetch)
origin  http://user@10.0.1.1/git/repo.git (push)
origin-vpn  http://user@10.0.2.1/git/repo.git (fetch)
origin-vpn  http://user@10.0.2.1/git/repo.git (push)
```

This is the same upstream repository, but I must access it through different endpoints depending on where I am.

Now I don't often use `origin-vpn`, and it sometimes lags behind as I don't fetch from it normally. But when I look at my `git log` I see all branches and tags duplicated from both origins.

I'd like to clean all data from `origin-vpn` as if I had never fetched from it. I need the `remote` to exist as I may use it from time to time, but I don't want any `refs` from it to show up.

How can I do this? If there is no command for that, is it enough and *safe* to use `git remote delete` and `git remote add` again and would that remove all those refs?

*Edit*: This is how I see my git log:

```
alias gitlog='git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-commit'
```

Comment: I must admit I don't really see why this is a problem. How does the presence of lagging heads clutter `git log` output? Normally, `git log` just displays the log of the current `HEAD` and is completely unaffected by other branches. Having another remote that is lagging behind shouldn't normally be an issue. I myself have lots of them, and have never had trouble with it.

Comment: Ummmph it's indeed not an enormous deal but they are duplicated: almost the same name, sometimes in different commits... it's kinda messy. My `gitlog` alias shows the entire commit tree, added it to the question (I recommend it!).

Comment: Even when I run your exact command, I don't get duplicated commits printed just because I have lagging remotes. The lagging remotes are simply printed as "tags" on the commits that would have been printed anyway.

Comment: [To wit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fDPCN.png). Lots of lagging remotes, no duplicated commits.

Comment: Exactly, but to me since the two origins are actually the same one, I hate to see those duplicates! I guess it's a matter of taste. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Oh, was that actually what you were referring to? Personally, I'd think it would only be useful to know how much certain remotes are lagging behind, but each to his own, I guess.

Comment: Just to clarify: but they are not really lagging behind, they just seem so because I don't fetch from the second remote (I can't, since that IP doesn't exist from my usual workplace). So I'm forced to see outdated information until I get to work from home again, which is when I am able to fetch from the second origin. Note that the two origins point to the same repository, but I cannot update both origins whenever I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove a remote's refs from a local repository, you will need to do as you suggested and `git remote rm origin-vpn`. This will just remove the local copies of the remote and all of its references as well as configuration (upstream tracking branches).

At this point in time, I would immediately add the remote back but NOT fetch it. This will keep the vpn remote as a possible push/pull/fetch location (specifically by name) but not have any of its references clogging up your local repo.

So long as you do not set the upstream tracking branches to the vpn remote, a standard pull/fetch should only pull down the origin remotes refs and not the vpn.

Comment: Thanks, this was the clarification I was looking for: "This will just remove the local copies of the remote and all of its references as well as configuration (upstream tracking branches).".

Comment: So one exception that I'm finding to this is lightweight tags. Once you pull the tags in, they are not associated with a remote, they didn't go away when the remote was removed. This seems to be corroborated by the fact that the .git/refs/tags dir is not located under .git/refs/remotes (that is, the tags are global). So it appears that if one repo had local tags that you pulled in, they can propagate to other repos and will just spread.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative: Since you state that you only pull from `origin-vpn` seldom, you may not actually need to set up a remote for it at all, in case you weren't already aware.

Functionally, a remote isn't really all that much more than an alias for a URL, and you can simply pull from the URL without setting up a remote for it:

```
git pull http://user@10.0.2.1/git/repo.git master
```

If you're actually planning to remove and recreate the `origin-vpn` remote every time you use it, then this seems simpler.

Comment: Didn't know this either, thanks! (my point however is to keep the remote as a reference to avoid forgetting the IP and port).